# Weierstrass M-test for uniform convergence

Tags: analysis

With the Weierstrass M-test for uniform convergence where for a functions $f_r:A \to \mathbb{R}$ you find an $M_r \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\forall x \in A, |f_r(x)| \leq M_r $. Can the $M_r$ be also a function of $x$? Or do you have to essentially find the $\|f_r\|_\infty$ each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant has to be chosen *independently* of $x$, though it is sufficient to find *any* sequence of constants which bound the functions and converge in sum. Often you will indeed be finding the supremum norm, but sometimes there will be a less precise, more obvious bound that is more convenient. For example for $x\in[0,1]$ we can show that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (x/n) \cos(4x/3n)}{n^2} $$
converges uniformly almost straight away, but the precise supremum norm is not so immediate.